# to_datetime in Python

Tags: qgis, python, datetime

I'm using QGIS 3.4 and I want to know how to convert a column datatype from string to datetime in python. I found that we can do that by to_datetime from the calculator but I want to do it from Python. Here is my data like:
[image: sample data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the python [datatime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module:

```
import datetime
str_date = '2019-11-17 15:42:04'
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

In QGIS 3 you can use the following expression:

```
to_datetime('2019-11-17 15:42:04')
```

Answer (score 0):

The [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) package has a nice function that could help: [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)